# cookie-session: req.session is null but cookies are not removed from browser

Tags: nestjs, cookie-session

According to [cookie-session docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session#destroying-a-session) Destroying a session can be done with `req.session = null`

In my Nestjs application I get the session (using the session decorator) and assign a `userId` property to it.

```
  @Post('/signin')
  @Serialize(UserDto)
  async signin(@Body() body: SigninUserDto, @Session() session: any) {
    const user = await this.authService.signin(body);
    session.userId = user.id;
    return user;
  }
```

This creates a session in the browser:
[image]

On signout, I set the session to null, as per the documentation, and in the browser, the session cookie is still visible. Why is it not removed; does this present a security concern; and how does one remove the session if it is a security concern?

```
  @Post('/signout')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @Serialize(UserDto)
  signout(@Session() session: any) {
    session = null;
  }
```

Edit: Some additional info - On the frontend I created a basic login form using NextJS that redirects the user to a home page with a simple logout button. the logout button sends an api call to the signout endpoint in my NestJS application that assigns `session=null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you inspect cookie contents? Probably `session = null` removes some session-data from cookie and leaves just a blank cookie

If not:

You could try to use `@Req() req: Request` and then call `req.session = null`

Comment: Accessing the session via the request works! Specifically when the req is of type Request from express, the cookie data is removed when setting it with req.session=null. Using the NestJs built-in Request type doesnt work. 

When I retrieve the session with the nestjs @session decorator, session = null doesn't appear to trigger the browser to clear the cookie data. The cookie value remains the same encrypted string whereas I would expect the encrypted string to change if the contents were changed.